# How do I add python libraries to an AWS lambda function for Alexa?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I was following the tutorial to create an Alexa app using Python:

[Python Alexa Tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/alexa-skill-tutorial)

I was able to successfully follow all the steps and get the app to work.I now want to modify the python code and use external libraries such as `import requests`
 or any other libraries that I install using pip. How would I setup my lambda function to include any pip packages that I install locally on my machine?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As it is described in the Amazon official documentation link [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)  It is as simple as just creating a zip of all the folder contents after installing the required packages in your folder where you have your python lambda code.

As Vineeth pointed above in his comment,  The very first step in moving from an inline code editor to a zip file upload approach is to change your lambda function handler name under configuration settings to include the python script file name that holds the lambda handler.

**lambda_handler =>  {your-python-script-file-name}.lambda_handler**.

[image: CONFIGURE LAMBDA FUNCTION]

Other solutions like [python-lambda](https://github.com/nficano/python-lambda) and [lambda-uploader](https://github.com/rackerlabs/lambda-uploader) help with simplifying the process of uploading and the most importantly LOCAL TESTING. These will save a lot of time in development.

Comment: This way is not working for python 3.6 script with psycopg2. Getting error "Unable to import module 'ProcessRawRetailSalesUsingCOPY': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'" i am using windows7 prof with pycharm. Need some help on this if you can.

Comment: Can we do that and still be able to modify the code inline? It seems that after adding a number of libraries, the zip file is large and it doesn't allow me to update the code inline anymore (th code itself is not large). Any workaround for this?

Comment: @Sarah package all your libraries in to a lambda layer and just keep your source code in your lambda zip and layer dependency to your lambda. This will reduce the size and you should be able to edit your code in line. Also checkout aws sam templates here => https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html

Comment: Can you take a look here? I am already doing what you suggested i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295967/no-module-named-requests-in-lambda-function?noredirect=1#comment127724357_72295967

Answer (score 28):

The [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) is pretty good. In a nutshell, you need to create a zip file of a directory containing both the code of your lambda function and all external libraries you use at the top level.

You can simulate that by deactivating your virtualenv, copying all your required libraries into the working directory (which is always in `sys.path` if you invoke a script on the command line), and checking whether your script still works.

Comment: I tried following the documentation. I pip installed the requests into the library. I took the color_game.py and added `import requests` at the top, requests directory, and requests-2.11.0.dist-info directory and sent those three to a zip file. I uploaded the zip file to lambda but when I try to run the Alexa function; it does not work. I get `The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.`

Comment: I figured it out! I realized I wasn't changing the name of my handler. It should be the filename.lambda_handler if you go from inline code to a zip file. Thanks!

Comment: We just started a project [bstpy](https://github.com/bespoken/bstpy) to expose a Python lambda as an http service. You may find it useful for testing. You can throw json payloads at it with curl or postman. If you try it with other  [Bespoken Tools](https://github.com/bespoken/bst) you can a have very nice development environment.

Comment: not blaming the messenger but this is a kluge on AWS's part. There should really be a more structured way to from pip/conda requirements to lambda deployment.

Comment: `The official documentation is pretty good.` Gonna have to disagree with you there. The title and the first sentence of the page you linked to alone are entirely unclear to me as to whether they even have anything to do with importing packages to my AWS instance. (Is it about packaging something I've created? Who knows!)

Comment: We started [juniper](https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper) as a way to automates the creation of python based artifacts as described in the official documentation. Building the zip manually is not a scalable solution, juniper was born out of our frustration building these artifacts with custom shell scripts.

Comment: Can you take a look here? I am already doing what you suggested i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295967/no-module-named-requests-in-lambda-function?noredirect=1#comment127724357_72295967

Answer (score 8):

You may want to look into using frameworks such as [zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) which will handle packaging up and deploying the lambda function for you.

You can use that in conjunction with [flask-ask](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask) to have an easier time making Alexa skills.  There's even a video tutorial of this (from the zappa readme) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjWV4R2P4ks)

Answer (score 8):

To solve this particular problem we're using a library called [juniper](https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper). In a nutshell, all you need to do is create a very simple manifest file that looks like:

```
functions:
  # Name the zip file you want juni to create
  router:
    # Where are your dependencies located?
    requirements: ./src/requirements.txt.
    # Your source code.
    include:
    - ./src/lambda_function.py
```

From this manifest file, calling `juni build` will create the zip file artifact for you. The file will include all the dependencies you specify in the requirements.txt.

The command will create this file `./dist/router.zip`. We're using that file in conjunction with a sam template. However, you can then use that zip and upload it to the console, or through the awscli.

Comment: Last commit is from 2019.

Answer (score 4):

Echoing @d3ming's answer, a framework is a good way to go at this point. Creating the deployment package manually isn't impossible, but you'll need to be uploading your packages' compiled code, and if you're compiling that code on a non-linux system, the chance of running into issues with differences between your system and the Lambda function's deployed environment are high.

You can then work around that by compiling your code on a linux machine or Docker container.. but between all that complexity you can get much more from adopting a framework.

[Serverless](http://serverless.com) is well adopted and has support for custom python packages. It even integrates with Docker to compile your python dependencies and build the deployment package for you.

If you're looking for a full tutorial on this, [I wrote one for Python Lambda functions here.](http://joshuaballoch.github.io/custom-packages-lambda/)

Answer (score 4):

Amazon created a repository that deals with your situation:
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/master/sample-apps/blank-python

The blank app is an example on how to push a lambda function that depends on requirements, with the bonus that being made by Amazon.

Everything you need to do is to follow the step by step, and update the repository based on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For some lambda POCs and fast lambda prototyping you can include and use the following function `_install_packages`, you can place a call to it before lambda handling function (for lambda init time package installation, if your deps need less than 10 seconds to install) or place the call at the beginning of the lambda handler (this will call the function exactly once at the first lambda event). Given pip install options included, packages to be installed must provide binary installable versions for manylinux.

```
_installed = False
def _install_packages(*packages):
    global _installed
    if not _installed:
        import os
        import sys
        import time
        _started = time.time()
        os.system("mkdir -p /tmp/packages")
        _packages = " ".join(f"'{p}'" for p in packages)
        print("INSTALLED:")
        os.system(
            f"{sys.executable} -m pip freeze --no-cache-dir")
        print("INSTALLING:")
        os.system(
            f"{sys.executable} -m pip install "
            f"--no-cache-dir --target /tmp/packages "
            f"--only-binary :all: --no-color "
            f"--no-warn-script-location {_packages}")
        sys.path.insert(0, "/tmp/packages")
        _installed = True
        _ended = time.time()
        print(f"package installation took: {_ended - _started:.2f} sec")

  # usage example before lambda handler
  _install_packages("pymssql", "requests", "pillow")
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
        pass # lambda code

  # usage example from within the lambda handler
  def lambda_handler(event, context):
        _install_packages("pymssql", "requests", "pillow")
        pass # lambda code
```

Given examples install python packages: `pymssql`, `requests` and `pillow`.

An example lambda that installs `requests` and then calls `ifconfig.me` to obtain it's egress IP address.

```
import json

_installed = False


def _install_packages(*packages):
    global _installed
    if not _installed:
        import os
        import sys
        import time
        _started = time.time()
        os.system("mkdir -p /tmp/packages")
        _packages = " ".join(f"'{p}'" for p in packages)
        print("INSTALLED:")
        os.system(
            f"{sys.executable} -m pip freeze --no-cache-dir")
        print("INSTALLING:")
        os.system(
            f"{sys.executable} -m pip install "
            f"--no-cache-dir --target /tmp/packages "
            f"--only-binary :all: --no-color "
            f"--no-warn-script-location {_packages}")
        sys.path.insert(0, "/tmp/packages")
        _installed = True
        _ended = time.time()
        print(f"package installation took: {_ended - _started:.2f} sec")

    # usage example before lambda handler


_install_packages("requests")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import requests
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(requests.get('http://ifconfig.me').content.decode())
    }
```

Given single quote escaping is considered when building pip's command line, you can specify a version in a package spec like this `pillow<9`, the former will install most recent 8.X.X version of pillow.

Answer (score 1):

I too struggled for a while with this. The after deep diving into aws resources I got to know the lambda function on aws runs locally on a a linux. And it's very important to have the the python package version which matches with the linux version.

You may find more information on this on : 
https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Follow the steps to download the version.
 1. Find the .whl image of the package from pypi and download it on you local.
 2. Zip the packages and add them as layers in aws lambda
 3. Add the layer to the lambda function.

Note: Please make sure that version you're trying to install python package matches the linux os on which the aws lambda performs computes tasks.

References : 
https://pypi.org/project/Pandas3/#files

Answer (score 1):

A lot of python libraries can be imported via Layers here: https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers, or your can use a framework like serverless that has plugins to package packages directly into your artifact.