# Got error using paramiko to connect to ec2 from lambda function

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to ssh from lambda to `ec2` to run script in `ec2` using paramiko, 
There is no problem with the deployment package , i successfully deployed the python package and uploaded to lambda . 
But while testing I got

> /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.so): ImportError

I installed `paramiko` and `cryptography` from pip in `ec2` environment.

Basically followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) to create the deployment package.

Comment: So you should install these python modules in labmda not ec2.

Comment: how could we install modules in lambda ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add python libraries to an AWS lambda function for Alexa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877058/how-do-i-add-python-libraries-to-an-aws-lambda-function-for-alexa)

Comment: its not the problem of deployment , while  testing the error occured.