# can't import pubsub on aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Python app that uses Google Cloud Pubsub, like this:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
```

It works fine locally, but on calling the AWS Lambda function I get:

```
Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name 'pubsub'
```

and no other error or details.

My requirements.txt file:

```
requests
google-cloud-datastore==1.4.0
google-cloud-pubsub==0.29.0
sqlalchemy
```

I have a feeling it may be do to the psutil requirement of pubsub, as when I try to import psutil before pubsub, I get this error:

```
Unable to import module 'handler': cannot import name '_psutil_linux'
```

Comment: this seems more like a question about how you are uploading the deployment package, since lambda does not provide those requirements for you. Can you give more detail about how you are uploading your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add python libraries to an AWS lambda function for Alexa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877058/how-do-i-add-python-libraries-to-an-aws-lambda-function-for-alexa)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [serverless](http://www.serverless.com) library, the solution is to do the following:

delete the .requirements folder in your project directory

add this to your serverless.yml file (docs [here](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements)):

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
```

Comment: you should update your question and maybe tag it as using the serverless framework

Answer (score 0):

You will need to prepackage your lambda function in a zip file that includes your external module.

`pip install module-name -t /path/to/project-dir`

Then compress your code with the modules included and upload the zip file.

For Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html