# Importing the OpenAI Python dependency into AWS Lambda fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openai-api, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to add the OpenAI Python library to my AWS Lambda function. I tried to add them via AWS Lambda Layers as described in [this](https://medium.com/@gauravkachariya/how-to-add-external-python-libraries-to-aws-lambda-499674113fb7) guide. However, when executing my code, the addition of this line:

```
import openai
```

leads to this error-response:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "c19b73e3-8c6d-4564-8be6-af7b03a79e00",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: c19b73e3-8c6d-4564-8be6-af7b03a79e00 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: c19b73e3-8c6d-4564-8be6-af7b03a79e00
REPORT RequestId: c19b73e3-8c6d-4564-8be6-af7b03a79e00  Duration: 5.02 ms   Billed Duration: 6 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 40 MB  Init Duration: 166.39 ms
```

When following along the guide using the same package as them (requests), importing that package (requests) doesn't lead to an error.

Are there possible explanations for this behavior? I don't know where to start looking for fixes. Or are there any alternative methods of importing the library?

Answer (score 0):

Your uploaded Lambda environment / Layer does not have `pydantic` installed which is a [requirement](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/requirements.lock) of the `openai` python package.

Ensure that all the required packages are installed in your folder where you have your python Lambda code before zipping and uploading to AWS via the console.

That being said, there is a similar [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877058/how-do-i-add-python-libraries-to-an-aws-lambda-function-for-alexa) that refers to the same part of the documentation like you.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue over and over again, and I finally found the solution. You have a couple of options to tackle this, in my case, I used Serverless Framework but if you're even using SAM that's fine as well.

i) So the quick approach is to dockerize your lambda, and change the architecture as arm instead of x86. You can dockerize your lambda using this Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
CMD ["handler.generate_code"]
```

ii) The second option is, to use the `serverless-python-requrements` plugin if you're using the serverless framework and have the followign configuration

```yaml
 pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerRunCmdExtraArgs: ["--platform", "linux/x86_64"]
    usePipenv: false
    slim: true
    layer: true
```

This one is flexible because you can use either x86 or arm depending on the `dockerRunCmdExtraArgs`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Layer which you uploaded to Lambda doesn't have all dependent packages.

Here is step to create layer for python, wish it will help.

- Check the python version in local machine and Lambda (It should be similar) as few packages are not imported properly when different version is there.
- Create Zip file in below mentioned path:

```
# Create Virtual environment for python3.

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

# Create a directory with name "python"

mkdir python
cd python

# Install you packages in this folder.

pip3 install pycryptodome -t .
Once installed Check the packages.

#Create ZIP file for python directory
cd .. 
zip -r deployment_name.zip python
```

- Now you can upload the .zip file to you AWS Lambda Layer.
  **Make sure the ZIP file is created for all folder available in python folder Don't miss out any files or folders it may be our main package may be dependent on it.**

---

**For Windows**

- Using power shell or Command Prompt perform following steps (admin privileges):

```
mkdir layers
cd layers
mkdir python
cd python
pip3 install pycryptodome -t ./
```

- Now open the python folder in file explorer.
- Zip the python folder along with its child folders.
- Now you are good to go and upload it as layer in AWS.

**It will great if you have Linux Machine or Create an EC2 Instance with Ubuntu AMI and Copy the Content to S3, the you can upload it from S3 bucket to AWS lambda layer directly.**